# including toMany list of IDS in REST response from sailsjs

Tags: rest, sails.js

I have a sails model ("Folders"):

```
module.exports =

  attributes: {
    name: type: 'string'
    parent: model: 'folder'
    folders: 
      collection: 'folder'
      via: 'parent'
```

When I retrieve via REST API, I want a response that looks like:

```
[ { name: 'foo', parent: 34, folders: [292, 358] } ]
```

However, sails leaves out the "folders" attribute.

What is the simplest way to get toMany included (this is just one example -- there are more toMany's, but OTOH I don't want them always to be included -- should be configurable per-relation)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "toMany" associations are suppressed by the default "toJSON" method that sails provides.

To override, in the object definition, inside of objects, override toJSON:

```
_ = require 'lodash'

attributes: { 
  ...

  toJSON: ()->
    return _.extend {}, this
```

This will use the defaults provided by "JSON.stringify", and the "toMany" relationships will be sent as lists of IDs (if this is what your adapter has returned for your model).